# libpoppel.so.7 is missing when running xournal

Tags: installation, package-management

When I try to run xournal I get the following error:

> xournal: error while loading shared
>   libraries: libpoppler.so.7: cannot
>   open shared object file: No such file
>   or directory

I should note that I `ln -s` the prviuos errors since the *.so.i had i smaller than the one I had installed.

How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of the shared object is 13 in natty: `/usr/lib/libpoppler.so.13`.